# Cannot access values from other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am pretty new with Rails. What I am trying to do is access the branch name and product name of a sale. I assigned associations with the three models (Sale,Branch,Product). However, I am unable to retrieve values. In the 'index.html.erb' view, it displays a nil value for the branch name and product name. How can I access the values?

sale.rb

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :branch, :class_name => "Branch", :foreign_key => :branch_code
  belongs_to :product, :class_name => "Product", :foreign_key => :product_sku
end
```

branch.rb

```
class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :sales, :class_name => "Sale", :foreign_key => :branch_code
end
```

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :sales, :class_name => "Sale", :foreign_key => :product_sku
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Sales Index</h1>

<h2>Files in database</h2>
<table border=2>
    <tr>
        <th>Branch Name</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Qty. Sold</th>
        <th>End of day Qty</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Date Created</th>
        <th>Date Last Modified</th>
    </tr>

    <% @sales.each do |sale| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= sale.branch %></td>
            <td><%= sale.product %></td>
            <td><%= sale.quantity_sold %></td>
            <td><%= sale.end_of_day_quantity %></td>
            <td><%= sale.salesdate %></td>
            <td><%= sale.created_at %></td>
            <td><%= sale.updated_at %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

sales_controller.rb

```
class SalesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @files = Dir.glob('/Users/xxyy/Documents/rails/Dummy/*.csv')
        #@mapper = Array.new() 
        require 'csv'
        require 'fileUtils'
        for file in @files

            filename = File.basename(file, ".*")
            date = filename[22..31]
            csv_text = File.read(file)

            CSV.foreach(file, :headers => true) do |row|
                Sale.create(:branch_code => row[0], :product_sku => row[1], :quantity_sold => row[2], :end_of_day_quantity => row[3], :salesdate => date)
            end
            FileUtils.mv(file, '/Users/xxyy/Documents/rails/Read/')
        end
        @sales = Sale.all

    end
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140812013013) do

  create_table "branches", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "branch_code"
    t.string   "branch_name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "products", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "product_sku"
    t.string   "product_name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "sales", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "branch_code"
    t.string   "product_sku"
    t.integer  "quantity_sold"
    t.integer  "end_of_day_quantity"
    t.integer  "branch_id"
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.datetime "salesdate"
  end

  add_index "sales", ["branch_id"], name: "index_sales_on_branch_id"
  add_index "sales", ["product_id"], name: "index_sales_on_product_id"

end
```

Comment: Could you please show us your controller code for this view?

Comment: In your view, what do you see on the page if you attempt to display the number of records, *e.g.*, `<p>Number of sales = <%= @sales.count %></p>`?

Comment: It displays "Number of sales = 372"

Comment: Do you get 372 rows of nil values for each attribute, or just nothing, or what?

Comment: I'm getting all the attributes except for the branch name and product name. I think this has something to do with the associations. I'm pretty new with this and I have no idea why I cannot get the values.

Comment: You really should have made that clear in your problem statement rather than just saying, *However, I am unable to retrieve values. In the 'index.html.erb' view, it displays a nil value.* which sounds more like you can't retrieve anything. And you're correct: it has everything to do with the associations. You're creating your `Sale` table from CSV files in your sales controller. Where did you create your `Branch` and `Product` tables? Do they already exist somewhere?

Comment: I edited the question. Thank you for correcting the vague details. I created it via the command line using "bin/rails g model Branch branch_code:string branch_name:string"

Comment: That only creates the models. It doesn't create the data in the tables. You need data migrations or scripts to populate the Branch and Product tables, so they're empty and you're getting nil in the associations. You should also be using migrations or seeds to create your Sale table rather than doing it in the controller. See for example: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html. The `schema` you're showing just defines the structure of the tables. It doesn't provide data.

Comment: No. I populated the tables once so they are not empty.

Comment: How did you populate them? And how do you know the `branch_code` and `product_sku` values in your CSV table align with the keys actually used in those created tables?

Comment: Yeah. After creating the model, I actually created the migration. Sorry I wasn't able to mention that. When I try to list all the records in the Branch model, it is returning all the values I entered during the migration.

Comment: The keys are aligned. I've double checked it.

Comment: It's not clear what's wrong then. I would go into the `rails console` and check a couple of `Sale` records by hand. Look at the attributes, especially the foreign keys for them, and make sure that the foreign keys really do point to valid `Branch` and `Product` records.

Comment: Just to clear the aim of the code, I pre-populated the values for the Branch and Product table. What I want to do is simply to reference these pre-populated values via the keys per sale item.

Comment: In your view, replace `<%= sale.branch %>` into `<%= sale.branch_code %>` or `<%= sale.branch.branch_code %>` , what will happen?

Comment: I've rollback your replacement of the question by a solution. Please find [your solution in the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8505e180-5ac4-4704-bfbb-2311ffd27cca/view-source) and post it as an answer of its own.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the associations done right.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sales, :class_name => "Sale", :foreign_key => :product_sku
end
```

Answer (score -2):

```
has_many :sales
```

This needs to be plural.

```
class Branch < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :sales
end
```

You don't need to specify the class name here and the foreign key should be branch_id (I'm guessing) which also doesn't need to be specified.

Comment: Still not working. And the reason why I am not using the branch_id as the key but the branch_code instead.

Comment: Can you post your schema.rb?

Comment: also, you shouldn't be creating records in the index action... this doesn't make sense. Are you trying to load dummy data? or is this part of the application?

Comment: I have to run now, but it doesn't make sense to have the foreign key set to branch_code on both Sale and Branch. I think one of these must be wrong.

Comment: OK, just had another look... You aren't creating these records in the controller eg: Sale.branches.create ... so there is no record to reference.

Comment: I pre-populated the values for the Branch and Product table. What I want to do is simply to reference these pre-populated values via the keys per sale item.